# "Index" and "range" operators - what are they?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was adjusting code style settings for C# and I noticed these options:

"Prefer index operator:"

```
// Prefer:
var ch = value[^1];

// Over:
var ch = value[value.Length - 1];
```

"Prefer range operator:"

```
// Prefer:
var sub = value[1..^1];

// Over:
var sub = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
```

I'm struggling to find any reference on these. What does "index operator" and "range operator" mean in this case? How do you use them?

Comment: Code Settings, in Visual Studio or Visual Code?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. Studio

Comment: These are new features in [C# v8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) intended to help avoid some common programming bugs around bounds.

Comment: “Struggling”? A simple google search “Index and Range operators c#” made the trick: it’s a C# 8 [new feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess the main advantage of using index and range operators is their simplicity.

## Index Operator `^`

Index operator `^` means **from the end**. Consequently, `array[^1]` means first element from the end. It is analogous to the common indexing, `array[1]` means one element from the start. The index `^0` means the end.

## **Range Operator `..`**

As you have shown in your example above, it is much convenient to create substring using range operator. Range operator can be used to create subarrays as well. For example, 
 
`var array = new {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
 var range = array[2..5]` 
Here's Microsoft documentation for the above topics: [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Answer (score 2):

^^Great answer, especially the index explanation. The range operator really builds on the index operator, and I thought I'd add some color for the range operator explanation from the MS link:

The .. operator specifies the start and end of a range of indices as its operands. The left-hand operand is an **inclusive** start of a range. The right-hand operand is an **exclusive** end of a range.

*Either of operands can be an index from the start or from the end of a sequence*

[a..] is equivalent to a..^0

[..b] is equivalent to 0..b

[..] is equivalent to 0..^0

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
int start = 1;
int amountToTake = 3;
int[] subset = numbers[start..(start + amountToTake)];
Display(subset);  // output: 10 20 30

int margin = 1;
int[] inner = numbers[margin..^margin];
Display(inner);  // output: 10 20 30 40

string line = "one two three";
int amountToTakeFromEnd = 5;
Range endIndices = ^amountToTakeFromEnd..^0;
string end = line[endIndices];
Console.WriteLine(end);  // output: three
```